# I'm trying to override the value from another class using subclass/superclass

Tags: java, overriding

I want the final result of "price" to be (3 * size), when it's a special item, but the override doesn't work as expected. For example, if I type size 3.4, then I end up with $6.8 as the answer, even though I chose option 1, which should trigger the class SpecialItem.java, but for some reason it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Also, the teacher expects both classes (SpecialItem.java and Item.java) to be used with HomeItem.java, and SpecialItem.java must override Item.java with a new price, so I cannot just put all the functions in the same class.

HomeItem.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HomeItem
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double theHeight;
        double thePrice;
        int yesNo;

        Item theItem = new Item();
        SpecialItem theSpecialItem = new SpecialItem();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the item size in inches >> ");
        theHeight = input.nextDouble();
        theItem.setHeight(theHeight);

        System.out.print("Type 1 if it's a special item or 2 if it's not >> ");
        yesNo = input.nextInt();       
        input.nextLine();

        if(yesNo == 1)
        {
            theSpecialItem.setHeight(theHeight);
        }

        System.out.print(theItem.getHeight() + " costs $" + theItem.getPrice());       
    }

}
```

Item.java file contains:

```
public class Item
{
    double height;
    double price;

    public void setHeight(double theHeight)
    {
        height = theHeight;
        price = 2 * theHeight;
    }

    public double getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
}
```

SpecialItem.java file contains:

```
package mainfile;

public class SpecialItem extends Item
{
    @Override
    public void setHeight(double theHeight)
    {
        height = theHeight;
        price = 3 * theHeight;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are always printing the value of `theItem` ...clearly, you also have to do it for the `specialItem` in the `if` case

Comment: Thanks, AKSW. I added another override to SpecialItem.java, and it worked when I called this function: 

    @Override
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are calling system.out.println on object of Item class , You should call it on SpecialItem .